# CSS bottom border Hover effect that stays on active div

Tags: html, css

In essence I will have two links into separate divs and the hover effect is a bottom border of 2 pixel. My aim is that the border line remains once the user is on the active link instead of just vanishing right after.

```css
/* underline link on div*/
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #DE591B;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your `.active` class to the div and toggle it with Javascript (I give you a JQuery solution).

Add a new selector after the `.cool-link:hover::after` line.

Code

```js
$('.cool-link a').click(function(){
  $('.cool-link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.cool-link').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* underline link on div*/
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #DE591B;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after,
.cool-link.active::after /*this is it*/
 {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .9s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 cool-link active">
      <a href="#" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Still no joy, there must  be a sort of conflict as I tried that fix myself even before but did not work. Same as before:
http://binary10.space/sites/BWT/login2/

Comment: put the `active` class on the `div` instead of the `a`

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.cool-link:active:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and maybe add an `.active` class, on the link, depending on the current page

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use border on `a:after` rather than `div`. And for `active` code add `.cool-link a.active::after` same as `.cool-link a:hover::after`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".cool-link a").on("click", function() {
  $(".cool-link a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
/* underline link on div*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link {
  text-align: center;
}

.cool-link a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #DE591B;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link a:hover::after,
.cool-link a.active::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .9s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working in my case, I need to retain the over effect, (not a static underline), but once a div has ben clicked its border should stay active red...see my login box as reference: http://binary10.space/sites/BWT/login2/

Comment: @DanielePais for that you have to use jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` for toggling the class on click. I will update my answer shortly. You tagged your question as `html` and `css` and you also did not mentioned about adding class on click....so I thought you have the code for adding the class....

Comment: @DanielePais Updated!

Comment: your fix works for the link thanks. However, I am trying to achieve the same but for the <div> bottom border line on full width. See the link below, the hover effect "cool-link" is applied on a div so that the line extend nicely to the full length, I just want to find a fix for having the bottom line staying there on the div when active.

Comment: @DanielePais i updated my code according to your requirement...See the updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.
CSS

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #DE591B;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .9s;
}

.cool-link a:visited,
.cool-link a:focus,
.cool-link a:active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DE591B;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 cool-link">
      <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqaozbhL/

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This does the trick, however, I need to have the border line on a div and not in the link unfortunately. See this URL for an example http://binary10.space/sites/BWT/login2/

Comment: Also, when you click out of the link (for example, inside a text box, as in this case the user would), the border would disappear.